# Public key cryptography based on non-invertible matrices?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, matrices, cryptography

**Added Wed 13 Apr 2022**

I have written a short note with experimental data,
which shows not all pseudo keys are good keys.

[Public key cryptography based on non-invertible matrices](https://j.ludost.net/invertible2.pdf)

---

We got public key cryptography scheme based on non-invertible
matrices and would like to know how easy it is to break.

Working over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p$ large.
All matrices are square $n \times n$.

Alice chooses matrices $M_A,X_A$ and makes $P_A=M_A X_A$ public.

Bob chooses matrices $M_B,X_B$ and makes $P_B=M_B X_B$ public.

Assume $M_A,M_B$ are not invertible and satisfy $M_A M_B=M_B M_A$.

To ensure this, take the field to be finite and Alice and Bob
agree on a singular matrix $M_0$ and Alice chooses large integer
$N_A$ and set $M_A=M_0^{N_A}$ and Bob chooses large integer
$N_B$ and set $M_B=M_0^{N_B}$. Since powers of matrices commute,
$M_A,M_B$ commute. Observe that this is different from the discrete
logarithm since $M_A,M_B$ are unknown.

Assume that $X_A,X_B$ are invertible.

To exchange shared secret, Bob makes public $S_B=M_B P_A=M_B M_A X_A$
and Alice computes $S_B X_A^{-1}=M_B M_A$

Likewise, Alice makes public $S_A=M_A P_B=M_A M_B X_B$ and Bob computes
$S_A X_B^{-1}=M_A M_B$.

At this point, Alice and Bob have the shared secret $M_A M_B=M_B M_A$,
which is expected to be hard to find by adversary.

Also, everyone, including an adversary know

$P_A=M_A X_A,P_B=M_B X_B,S_A=M_A P_B,S_B=M_B P_A$.

If $P_B$ were invertible, adversary could break the scheme by computing
$S_A P_B^{-1}=M_A$.

> Q1 What is complexity of breaking this crypto scheme, i.e.
> given $P_A,P_B,S_A,S_B$, find $M_A M_B$?

> Q2 Can we replace matrices by some object
> and make a crypto scheme based on non-invertibility?

We are interested in choices of the matrices and the field for which
breaking the scheme is hard.

Treating the matrices as variables, we get $4n^2$ equations with $4n^2$ variables
and $2n^2$ of the equations are linear and the other equations are quadratic.

---

We got partial results about hardness.

The problem is given $P_A,P_B,S_A,S_B$, find $M_A M_B$.

Experimentally with a toy implementations, we found many
solutions which satisfy the construction, but don't give
the shared secret. If the number of potential solutions is large,
the scheme will be hard to break. For $p=3,n=3$, we got $27$ total solutions
and for $p=2,n=4$ we got $256$ total solutions.

In addition, there is algebraic attack. We have four unknown matrices,
set all their entries to variables.

We have four equations over matrices, two of which linear.
From the linear equation eliminate variables using gaussian elimination,
which leaves $2n^2$ quadratic equations.

sagemath toy implementation with many solutions:

https://pastebin.com/raw/Mb8yp3Gt

Comment: Since $M_A$ and $M_B$ are square matrices what you gain from the additional size of $n$ contributed by their null-spaces?

Comment: If Alice chooses $M_A$ and Bob chooses $M_B$, what insures that they commute?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I think I solved your commuting issue by editing with taking M_A,M_B to be powers of matrix M_0 and powers of matrices commute.

Comment: Couldn't you also solve that by "picking sides", i.e. one key is $P_A = X_AM_A$ and the other $P_B = M_BX_B$, and then communicate $S_B = P_AM_B = X_AM_AM_B$ (invert on the left to find $M_AM_B$) and $S_A = M_AP_B = M_AM_BX_B$ (invert on the right to find $M_AM_B$)? It just requires one extra bit of public communication (who is left and who is right), and greatly increases the set of admissible matrices.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I don't understand your attack, nothing is invertible. The further communication is based on the shared secret M_A M_B. Would you please explain the attack in an answer?

Comment: It's not an attack, it's an improvement. And $X_A$ and $X_B$ are invertible.

Comment: @joro sorry, my comment was in response to Steven Landsburg's comment. Except the order of multiplication, nothing is changed in comparison to the original question, so $X_A$ and $X_B$ are still invertible.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn aaa, now i understand, thanks. Very clever way to avoid commutativity.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg There is clever way to avoid commutativity, check R. van Dobben de Bruyn's comment.

Comment: joro:  yes, i'd already seen (and upvoted) @R.vanDobbendeBruyn 's clever comment.

Comment: I have found your notation hard to follow. As a summary to others, if you let $S\in M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)\setminus GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be singular (and public), $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ be secret (you should really specify a finite set for these though), and $A, B\in GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be secret, then the transcript of your protocol is $(S^aA, S^aB, S^{a+b}A, S^{a+b}B)$. The agreed upon secret at the end is $S^{a+b}$. Note that your protocol takes 4 rounds of communication, 2 is standard for efficient protocols. As communication takes ~200ms due to speed of light constraints, this difference is large.

Comment: "2 is standard for efficient protocols."-The number of rounds of communication only makes a difference once the protocol is ready to be used in real-life.

Comment: The abstract of the paper says "Experimental data suggests the algorithm is strong," if such a claim can be made, you should be able to tell me what portion of my algorithm that breaks this key exchange is incorrect. And even if this key exchange were not yet broken, one should not call it 'strong' based on computer experiments since computer experiments cannot predict all the ways an attacker can attack the key exchange to determine that it is safe.

Comment: @JosephVanName thanks, you are right. i edited the note, writing "Experimental data suggests the algorithm is not ready for usage"

Answer (score 1):

This key exchange is **broken**.

For this problem, let $\langle M_{0}\rangle$ denote the algebra generated by $M_{0}$.

Set $Z_{A}=X_{A}^{-1},Z_{B}=X_{B}^{-1}$. Then $M_{A}=P_{A}Z_{A},M_{B}=P_{B}Z_{B}$. In particular,
$S_{B}=P_{B}Z_{B}P_{A}$.

A pseudo key is a matrix $Z_{B}^{p}$ such that $P_{B}Z_{B}^{p}\in\langle M_{0}\rangle$ and where $S_{B}=P_{B}Z_{B}^{p}P_{A}$. The affine space of all pseudo keys can be computed simply by solving a system of linear equations.

If $Z_{B}^{p}$ is a pseudo key, then
$$M_{B}M_{A}=P_{B}Z_{B}P_{A}Z_{A}=S_{B}Z_{A}=P_{B}Z_{B}^{p}P_{A}Z_{A}=P_{B}Z_{B}^{p}S_{A},$$ so the secret key $M_{B}M_{A}$ is recoverable from a pseudo key $Z_{B}^{p}$ and the public information $S_{A}$.

Comment: Thanks. How do you explain the experimental observation that there are many solutions to the construction, but only few give the shared secret?

Comment: What do you mean by " An adversary will be able to recover MAMBy if the adversary has access to a pair like (MB,z)"? The public information is only 5 matrices (M0,P_A,P_B,S_A,S_B)?

Comment: Also, do you break the discrete logarithm for singular matrices? Can you find X such that M_0^X=A with M_0 singular? In the exchange you can fix one of the keys to be of your choice.

Comment: The discrete logarithm for singular matrices is not harder than the discrete logarithm for invertible matrices. If $M_{0}$ is a singular $n\times n$-matrix, then to solve $M_{0}^{X}=A$, one first puts $M_{0}$ into Jordan normal form. One can then test the cases when $X\leq n$ one by one, but if $X\geq n$, then all the Jordan blocks in $M_{0}^{X}$ with eigenvalue $0$ will become zero, so the problem for $X\geq n$ then reduces to the problem about solving the discrete logarithm for invertible matrices.

Comment: An addition to what Joseph Van Name wrote, no reason to go all the way to Jordan form. Just use find bases for $\text{Ker}(M^n)$ and $\text{Im}(M^n)$. These will be complementary, so we can use them to block diagonalize $M$ as $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} U&0 \\ 0&N \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ with $U$ invertible and $N$ nilpotent.